# nlsxbe.dll is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: java, windows, lotus-notes

I got below problem when I connect notes database, my jre is 32bit,windows is 64bit, is there anyone can help me?

```
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1648)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: nlsxbe (.\nlsxbe.dll is not a valid Win32 application. )
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1028)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:992)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:513)
at lotus.domino.NotesThread.load(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.NotesThread.checkLoaded(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What IBM Lotus software is installed on your machine? Lotus Notes client, or Lotus Domino server? Also, the error suggests that it is looking for nlsxbe.dll in your current directory. Are you running your code from the directory where you have the Lotus code installed?

Comment: I installed lotus Notes client, It run OK in my local machine,which use windows 7, jvm32bit, but it throw this error when we deploy to our server. so the code has no problem. I set the Path in c:\notes, I think the directory is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The Lotus Notes client only comes in 32 bit, but the Domino Server comes in both 64 bit and 32 bit versions. Since you have a 64 bit Windows OS, it is possible that your Domino server is 64 bit, which means that NLSXBE.DLL is 64 bits. A 32 bit JVM cannot load a 32 bit DLL.

You can check look at the answers to [this question][1] for info about how to tell whether your NLSXBE.DLL is 64 or 32 bit.

If I'm right about this, you have three choices: upgrade your JVM to 64 bit, downgrade your Domino server installation from 64 to 32 bit, or run your code on a different machine with properly matched JVM and NLSXBE.DLL bitness.

Comment: Hi,I found, there are two nlsxbe.dll in my machine, first notes9 nlsxbe.dll is32bit, but domino is 64bit, but in environment variable I setting c:\notes, it should be find nlsxbe.dll of notes

Comment: I uninstall my domino Sever, but the problem still exists

Comment: Is it still saying "./nlxbe.dll" in the error message? That implies it is looking in the current directory. Are you running your code in the Notes client program directory?

Comment: yes,it still show the error message, there are only one"nlsxbe.dll" in my computer now. It's 32bit

Comment: But are you running your code in the same directory that nlsxbe.dll is in?  What happens if you rename nlsxbe.dll to something like nlsxbe2.dll? Do you get the exact same error message?

Comment: yes, in same directory, If I rename it,It will show nlsxbe (Not found in java.library.path)

Comment: I got this problem again, I only install notes, no domino server, and only one nlsxbe.dll in system, the problem shows again

Comment: Did you install 64 bit Notes, or 32 bit Notes?

Comment: I find we use websphere, and the JRE is 64bit, Notes is 32bit, but we can't change the setting of websphere. so can we try to use domino server's notes.jar to run program. It shows nlsxbe.dll %1 is not a valid win32 application

Comment: we use 64 bit JRE, 64bit notes.jar from domino server, it shows nlsxbe.dll %1 is not a valid win32 application

Comment: There is no such thing as a 64 bit notes.jar. Jar files are universal and run on 64 and 32 bit JREs. But a 64 bit JRE cannot call a 32 bit DLL, so it cannot call the nlsxbe.dll from a 32 bit Notes install.

Comment: but we have nlsxbe.dll 64 bit in domino server, I means can we use 64 bit JRE call 64bit nlsxbe.dll from domino server

Comment: I'm sorry. I am lost. You said above "I only install notes, no domino server, and only one nlsxbe.dll in system". Now you're back to talking about the server. I have no idea what is true. StackOverflow discourages long discussion threads for troubleshooting because it's a sign that the situation is simply too complex or too poorly described to reach an answer that is generally useful to other people who come to read this topic later.. I'm afraid I can't really help you here. I think you need an expert who can take a hands-on approach and examine your systems to help you find a solution.